# Will a sata3 SSD work properly on a Mac mini (Mid 2010) with 2.4 GHz CPU?

Tags: mac, mac-mini

I have a Mac mini (Mid 2010) with 2.4 GHz CPU and willing to upgrade its HDD to SSD.

Can I use a sata3 SSD for it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Here are the theoretical bus speeds

SATAI   - 150 MB/sec - 1.5 Gb/sec
SATAII  - 300 MB/sec -  3 Gb/sec 
SATAIII - 600 MB/sec -  6 Gb/sec

In theory, a very fast drive could saturate a SATA2 bus, but if it does, it will still send the data, just slower than it's capable of.  If that bothers you, just buy a slower SATA2 SSD drive.

Regardless, you'll be very happy with the performance upgrade over a slower drive.  It's the best upgrade investment you can make.

Answer (score 1):

SSDs with SATA-**X** are **backward compatible**.

- SATA3 is compatible with SATA3, SATA2 and SATA1 connections
- SATA2 is compatible with SATA2 and SATA1 connections

I for example use a SSD with a SATA3 capability on a SATA1 bus. (Crucial m4 in MBP 3.1)

*My advice:*
Always take the latest SSDs. They have a *more refined garbage collection.* It's also preferable to take a SSD with SATA3 in order to profit from the faster bus speed in case you use the SSD in another computer some day.

Answer (score -2):

Nope, because SATA3 in a Mini began with the 2011 models, or with Core i5/i7 processors. The SSD would saturate the SATA2 bandwidth, but I don't see why you would spend more money for the little extra speed it's gonna give you. Stick with SATA2 SSDs is my advice.

Comment: It's preferable to take a SATA3 in order to profit from the faster bus speed in case you use the SSD in another computer some day. SATA3 SSDs are backward compatible with SATA2.